# Passing REGEX string into re.search

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck when trying to substitute a variable into a re.search.
I use the following code to gather a stored regex from a file and save it to the variable "regex."  In this example the stored regex is used to find ip addresses with port numbers from a log message.

```
for line in workingconf:
    regexsearch = re.search(r'regex>>>(.+)', line)
    if regexsearch:
        regex = regexsearch.group(1)
        print regex

#I use re.search to go through "data" to find a match.

data = '[LOADBALANCER] /Common/10.10.10.10:10'
alertforsrch = re.search(r'%s' % regex, data)
if alertforsrch:
    print "MATCH"
    print alertforsrch.group(1)
else:
    print "no match"
```

When this program runs I get the following.

```
$ ./messageformater.py
/Common/([\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}:[\d]{1,})
no match
```

when I change re.search to the following it works.  The regex will be obtained from the file and may not be the same every time.  That is why I am trying to use a variable.

```
for line in workingconf:
    regexsearch = re.search(r'regex>>>(.+)', line)
    if regexsearch:
        regex = regexsearch.group(1)
        print regex


alertforsrch = re.search(r'/Common/([\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}:[\d]{1,})', data)
if alertforsrch:
    print "MATCH"
    print alertforsrch.group(1)
else:
    print "no match"

####### Results ########
$./messageformater.py
/Common/([\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}\.[\d]{1,}:[\d]{1,})
MATCH
10.10.10.10:10
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint after r'%s' % regex and comparing the string to what you expect it to be? Maybe there is some trailing space or control character that messes up the match.

Comment: Yes.  There is trailing information.  Answer provided by Sharp3 has solved the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me...

Why even bother with the string formatter though? re.search(regex, data) should work fine.

You may have a newline character at the end of the regex read in from the file - try re.search(regex.strip(), data)

Comment: The regex.strip() works perfectly.  It appears that the regex variable had some trailing information causing the the regex not to match.  Thanks for the help.